# Производительность SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Как правильно использовать транзакции SQlite? Может, плохо искал, но не нашел, как сделать правильно. Все выполняю в AsyncTask. Вот код:

```
DbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new DbOpenHelper(MainActivity.this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues qcv = new ContentValues();
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        qcv.put(DbOpenHelper.ID, 200 + k);
        qcv.put(DbOpenHelper.KEY1, "value1");
        qcv.put(DbOpenHelper.KEY2, "value2");
        db.insert(DbOpenHelper.TABLE2_NAME, null, qcv);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: db.setTransactionSuccessful(); по-моему надо вынести из цикла, и транзакции нужны для того, чтобы была возможность откатить изменения в виде последовательности действий. Например для работы проги надо сделать селект одной таблицы, потом инсерт и апдейт в другие нескольким потокам одновременно с одними и теми же данными, у одного не получится - можно откатить.

Comment: Дело в том, что использование транзакций, насколько мне известно, позволяет увеличивать производительность в разы, т.к. не выполняется открытие/закрытие базы данных при записи каждого элемента.

Comment: @andgo75 это заблуждение. Все зависит от уровня изоляций транзакций. Чем выше уровень изоляций тем ниже скорость. По умолчанию обычно стоит уровень READ_UNCOMMITTED - при этом достигается наивысшая скорость. Так что сэр вы ошибаетесь

Answer (score 1):

Нужно так:

```
try {
    db.beginTransaction();

    ///// работа с бд: select, update, insert...
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {

        // если внутри цикла нужно зафиксировать транзакцию,
        // (например, после обработки 100 insert'ов)
        // то пишем условие и:
        // db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        // db.endTransaction();
        // db.beginTransaction();

        qcv.put(DbOpenHelper.ID, 200 + k);
        qcv.put(DbOpenHelper.KEY1, "value1");
        qcv.put(DbOpenHelper.KEY2, "value2");
        db.insert(DbOpenHelper.TABLE2_NAME, null, qcv);
    }

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch(...) { 
    ...
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

хорошая практика. открыть бд в Application и закрывать там же.